# How to append matrices to an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have a for loop creating a matrix each time. Now, I want to put those matrices inside an array to use later.
I used np.append(), but it returns an empty array.

Below is my code:

```
x,y = 0
matrix = np.zeros((81, 81))  # declare an empty matrix to store values
for i in range(0,5):
    for row in rowList:
        matrix[y+40][x+40] = 1
    print np.count_nonzero(matrix)
    matrixArray = np.array([])
    np.append(matrixArray,matrix)
    print matrixArray
```

PS. I want to store the `matrix` into `matrixArray`, but the last

```
print matrixArray
```

returns

```
[]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is "rowList" ? Could you please add an example of rowList which allows reproduction of your error?

Comment: are you using numpy?

Comment: Further, you are Looping through a range, but not using the i in the loop

Comment: Please provide the example for `rowList`.

Comment: You are not saving the output of `np.append(matrixArray,matrix)` to a new array.  `np.append` does not happen in-place like with Python `list`s

Comment: Yes I'm using numpy. I just showed a few lines of my large file. The matrix all created correct, it is hard to show here how it is created. But the only problem is I cannot add them into the array.

Comment: Hi James? Can you say more specific of how to save the output?